# A python script to get username for a userid in tiktok

Tags: python, profile, userid, tiktok

I have a tiktok user id: 7044245546232743426. I would like to write a short python script to get the @username (and possibly other profile information) for this tiktokid. The solution must demonstrate that I receive the correct username and profile information for this popular tiktok userid.

Comment: You stated what you want but didn't explain what exact problem you encountered when doing this. You haven't actually asked any question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could use TikTokScraper.getUserProfileInfo()

See:
https://github.com/drawrowfly/tiktok-scraper#getUserProfileInfo